# Optimization on creating list of the first and second characters from MySQL using PHP

Tags: mysql

I've tried a lot to come up with an optimized version of creating list of my data using their first character and then refine it with another query retrieving the first two characters, then the whole data from that refining. Here are my current two queries and the structure of the table. The table has 14M+ rows of data and it's increasing. Similar approach needs to be applied on bigger tables for the same purpose.

Getting the list of first characters:

```
SELECT `Letter`, COUNT(`Letter`) AS `Count` FROM (SELECT LEFT(TRIM(`Words`), 1) AS `Letter` FROM `table_mywords`) `a` GROUP BY `Letter` ORDER BY `Letter`
```

Getting the list of first two characters (`$first_letter` is fed by PHP as a selected entry from above query):

```
SELECT `Letter`, COUNT(`Letter`) AS `Count` FROM (SELECT LEFT(TRIM(`Words`), 2) AS `Letter` FROM `table_mywords` WHERE LEFT(TRIM(`Words`), 1)='$first_letter') `a` GROUP BY `Letter` ORDER BY `Letter`
```

The third query is (`$firsttwo_letters` is fed by PHP as a selected entry from above query):

```
SELECT `Words` FROM `table_mywords` WHERE `Words` LIKE '$firsttwo_letters%' GROUP BY `Words` ORDER BY `Words`
```

The query times I'm getting is above 15 seconds on the first and like 25 secs on the second query.

The table structure goes as follow:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table_mywords` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `Unique` tinytext COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
  `Words` text COLLATE utf8_persian_ci NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_persian_ci;
ALTER TABLE `scipers_keywords`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  ADD UNIQUE KEY `Unique` (`Unique`(128),`Words`(128)),
  ADD KEY `Words_3` (`Words`(3)),
  ADD FULLTEXT KEY `Words` (`Words`),
  MODIFY `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;
```

**These are my tries already:**

*For the first query:*

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(LEFT(TRIM(`Words`), 1)) AS `Letter` FROM `table_mywords`
```

I used this query then sorted them using PHP's `sort()` but overall query time was still pretty much the same.

*For the second query:*

```
SELECT `Letter`, COUNT(`Letter`) AS `Count` FROM (SELECT LEFT(TRIM(`Words`), 2) AS `Letter` FROM `table_mywords` WHERE MATCH(`Words`) AGAINST ('+$first_letter*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)) `a` GROUP BY `Letter` ORDER BY `Letter`
```

The result was not very accurate nor faster.

```
SELECT `Letter`, COUNT(`Letter`) AS `Count` FROM (SELECT LEFT(TRIM(`Words`), 2) AS `Letter` FROM `table_mywords` WHERE MATCH(`Words`) AGAINST ('+$first_letter*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) AND  UPPER(LEFT(TRIM(`Words`), 1))=UPPER('$first_letter')) `a` GROUP BY `Letter` ORDER BY `Letter`
```

The result was accurate but much longer.

Also:

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(LEFT(TRIM(`Words`), 2)) AS `Letter` FROM `table_mywords` WHERE UPPER(LEFT(TRIM(`Words`), 1))=UPPER('$first_letter')
```

Didn't do much better or did even worse!

Your helps are very appreciated.

***UPDATE***

To overcome the problem I've change the logic a bit for now. Right now I record the list of the letters and their counts in a separate table and update them regularly. In this case while the list in the database is still good, I'll retrieve the list from the new table rather than a query from original data. But the main problem still exists even for that execution. Help is still needed.

Comment: What's the purpose of these queries? Are you trying to implement a keyword search?

Comment: I want to create a way for the users to access the data through listing. That data (say 'a') is basically some sort of characteristics of other table data (say 'b') and the users should be able to reach table 'b' data by fulltext search on table 'a'. 

I hope this was helpful

Comment: I'm a bit confused. you just mentioned two tables, `a` and `b`, but all your queries concern only one table, `table_mywords`.  I'm having trouble understanding what it looks like from the user's perspective.  Say I'm a user. What do I see? what do I do? Use real concepts please such as "cars", "jobs" etc.. instead of "a" and "b"

Comment: Ok, let's say we have two tables 'cars' and 'specifications'. All the queries that I mentioned above are for the specifications which are consist of words each as one data row (``table_mywords``). Multiple rows from the 'specifications' table is assigned to each row in the 'cars' table. My purpose of this question is to have a good listing approach for the specifications' words.

Comment: Ok, maybe I get it.  As a user, I select "car" and that triggers an http request. Your script takes `car` as input and looks through `specifications` table for all records that have to do with `car` and returns them. So you want a query to select all specifications given a specific `car`?

Comment: No! I want to make listing for all the specifications. Starting from their first letters, when they chose the first letter then a new list populates for all the specifications starting as selected and have two letters. Then by selecting the two-letter option, all the specifications starting by those two letters should be viewed. Finally by selecting each specifications all the cars having that selected specification are shown (this part is not intended in here).